# Query is executing without starting the PostgreSQL 9.6 Windows Service

Tags: postgresql, windows, postgresql-9.6

My postgres service has not started but I am able to execute any queries on the database. Will it happen like this?
Im using win10 OS, Postgres 9.6

[image]

When Iam trying to start the service, I'm getting an error message as the below.
[image]

Comment: If you can run a query on your database, your database is running. It doesn't have to be as a service (check running applications, you might have just started it as a programm). Or it can be a differently named service. You can use `netstat -anbo` as admin to look for anything listening on port 5432.

Comment: Did you find how your PostgreSQL process was started?

Comment: @Solarflare netstat helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL can be started using different methods.

You (or most probably some tool) are likely to have started PostgreSQL by using:

```
pg_ctl start -D /path/to/data
```

(Assuming `pg_ctl.exe` is in one directory in your `PATH`)

Note that this doesn't start PostgreSQL as a Windows Service; but it starts PostgreSQL anyhow (if all parameters and settings are correct).

Depending on *which* installer you used and which *settings* you chose, the installer created *also* a Windows Service that should start when your system starts. Normally, when you use this installation method, it also *starts the service*.

If you can *restart* your machine, it most probably will start the PostgreSQL service in the normal fashion. If it doesn't, it is probable that some other of your services is starting PostgreSQL behind the scenes.

We can probably be more precise if you let us know *which* installer you used (EnterpriseDB PostgreSQL installer tends to be the most commonly used for Windows).

---

References

1. [pg_ctl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-ctl.html)
2. [PostgreSQL Windows Installers](https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/)

Comment: TCP    [::1]:55861            PC-1:5432      ESTABLISHED;
  TCP    [::1]:56991            PC-1:5432      ESTABLISHED;
  TCP    [::1]:62055            PC-1:5432      ESTABLISHED;   you are right. netstat is giving some services in 5432